# Foreach results with joined tables

Tags: php, mysql

Ok i am using codeIgniter here is my query

```
function get_stories()
{  

   $this->db->from('stories');
   $this->db->join('stories_to_categories', 'stories.id = stories_to_categories.story');
   $this->db->join('categories', 'stories_to_categories.category = categories.id');
   $query = $this->db->get();
   return $query;
}
```

i am getting results

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [title_english] => 1
        [title_srpski] => 
        [subtitle_english] => 
        [subtitle_srpski] => 
        [logo] => 0
        [gallery] => 0
        [story_english] => 1
        [story_srpski] => 
        [uri_english] => 1
        [uri_srpski] => 
        [story] => 1
        [category] => 1
        [parent] => 0
        [name_english] => strategy
    )

    [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 2
        [title_english] => 1
        [title_srpski] => 
        [subtitle_english] => 
        [subtitle_srpski] => 
        [logo] => 0
        [gallery] => 0
        [story_english] => 1
        [story_srpski] => 
        [uri_english] => 1
        [uri_srpski] => 
        [story] => 1
        [category] => 2
        [parent] => 0
        [name_english] => external
    )

    [2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 3
        [title_english] => 1
        [title_srpski] => 
        [subtitle_english] => 
        [subtitle_srpski] => 
        [logo] => 0
        [gallery] => 0
        [story_english] => 1
        [story_srpski] => 
        [uri_english] => 1
        [uri_srpski] => 
        [story] => 1
        [category] => 3
        [parent] => 0
        [name_english] => internal
    )

    [3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 4
        [title_english] => 1
        [title_srpski] => 
        [subtitle_english] => 
        [subtitle_srpski] => 
        [logo] => 0
        [gallery] => 0
        [story_english] => 1
        [story_srpski] => 
        [uri_english] => 1
        [uri_srpski] => 
        [story] => 1
        [category] => 4
        [parent] => 0
        [name_english] => stakeholder
    )

    [4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 5
        [title_english] => 1
        [title_srpski] => 
        [subtitle_english] => 
        [subtitle_srpski] => 
        [logo] => 0
        [gallery] => 0
        [story_english] => 1
        [story_srpski] => 
        [uri_english] => 1
        [uri_srpski] => 
        [story] => 1
        [category] => 5
        [parent] => 0
        [name_english] => crisis
    )

)
```

And i am printing out

```
foreach($story->result() as $row)
{
    echo '
        <tr>
            <td>' . $row->title_english . '</td>
            <td>' . $row->name_english . ',<td>
    ';
}
```

in my table i am  having

```
1   strategy,   
1   external,   
1   internal,   
1   stakeholder,    
1   crisis,
```

I try to achieve

1   strategy,  external,   internal,stakeholder,crisis,
Can please someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use something like that

```
$results = array();

foreach($story->result() as $row){
  if(!isset($results[$row->title_english]))
    $results[$row->title_english] = array();      
  $results[$row->title_english][] = $row->name_english;    
}

foreach($results as $title_english => $names){
   echo '<tr><td>' . $title_english . '</td><td>' . implode(',',$names) . '</td><tr>';
}
```

This code creates another (actually 2-dimensional) array holding subarrays at the indexes given by `$row->title_english` values. After traversing your initial array and filling the new one, you can easily output vaules in desired format.

Comment: may you help me little more somehow i always get one result less from categories for example 1 strategy, external instead 1 strategy, external, internal

Comment: @VladimirStus Sorry, it was my mistake! That is good that you write me, look at update version of code in answer!

Comment: @zavh is there way to insert one more row into this loop i need also row->id fields for my app?

Comment: should i try something like this, add this lines   $results[$row->id] = array();      
  $results[$row->id][] = $row->id;

Comment: @VladimirStus Yes, use xode from answer as example

Answer (score -1):

Try to do this in your foreach:

```
foreach( $story->result() as $row )
{
    echo '
        <tr>
            <td>' . $row->title_english . '</td>
            <td>' . $row->name_english . ',</td>
        </tr>
    ';
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are forgetting the closing tr tag and the closing td tag.